# What is the minimum date time value that can be entered in MySQL column of timestamp datatype?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm trying to insert a date time value e.g. 1970-01-01 00:00:01 in a column of timestamp datatype in MySQL table but getting following error:

`#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '1970-01-01 00:00:01' for column 'order_date' at row 1`

[image]

But according to MySQL docs - The TIMESTAMP value has a range from '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

So if the range value starts from 1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC then why this value can't be inserted in the table? Is there something to do with `UTC`? What will be the minimum date time value for timestamp that can be inserted without any issue?

Comment: *time zone* matters

Comment: So how to calculate the final value of date time with UTC?

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp columns store a utc value and start at 1970-01-01 00:00:01, but whenever you read or write them, they convert to/from your session timezone.  This makes them something of a nightmare to work with if you are actually intending to only use UTC.

Just use a datetime type if you ever are trying to set particular times that come from your client.  If you must use timestamp and want to set a particular UTC time, first do:

```
set session time_zone='+00:00';
```

But note that any client that doesn't do that may see a different time.  Even if you set your server timezone to UTC, so that sessions default to UTC, some client libraries "helpfully" set the session timezone when they connect.

Comment: The time in range is 00:00:01 and not 00:00:00. So what to do if we need to insert only 1970-01-01 00:00:01?

Comment: Sorry, mistyped the second.   Adding to my answer.

Comment: Since, IST is 5 hours 30 minutes ahead from UTC, so minimum value I can enter will be 1970-01-01 05:30:01, right?

Comment: Should be, yes.